# How can I create a retrofit Response<Void> and set the code myself?

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I have to create a successful `Response<Void>` with different codes, for some unit tests I'm writing.
I've tried `val response: Response<Void> = Response.success(209, null)`, but the compiler complains with an 'overload resolution ambiguity' alert. I can create the response with `val response: Response<Void> = Response.success(null)`, but I need to be able to set the code myself.

Any ideas?

Edit:
I can do this: `val response: Response<String> = Response.success(209, "abc")`, but when the type is `Void`, it doesn't work.

Comment: Mock the response?

Comment: @JakeB I'm also unable to set the code in a mocked Response object.

Comment: Managed to solve?